# How to return multiple values with different types (one of them a data class) from a function in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, return, return-value, return-type

I have the following piece of code:

```
data class DMSAngle(var degree: Double, var minute: Double, var second: Double)

fun coordinateInverseCalculation(point1: Point3D, point2: Point3D){

    val horizontalDistance = sqrt(
        (point2.easting - point1.easting).pow(2.0) +
            (point2.northing - point1.northing).pow(2.0)
    )

    val heightDifference = point2.height - point1.height

    val slopePercent = (heightDifference / horizontalDistance) * 100

    val slopeDistance = sqrt(
        (point2.easting - point1.easting).pow(2.0) +
                (point2.northing - point1.northing).pow(2.0) +
                (point2.height - point1.height).pow(2.0)
    )

    val point12D = Point(easting = point1.easting, northing = point1.northing)
    val point22D = Point(easting = point2.easting, northing = point2.northing)
    val g12 = gizement(point12D, point22D)
    val g12DMS = decimalDegreesToDMS(g12)
}
```

I want the values `horizontalDistance: Double`, `heightDifference: Double`, `slopePercent: Double`, `slopeDistance: Double` and `g12DMS: DMSAngle` to be returned from the function. How can I do this?

I also need a comprehensive guide in order to understand how to return multiple values (with or without different types) from a function in Kotlin. [I have read about this](https://www.google.com/search?q=return%20multiple%20values%20with%20different%20types%20from%20function%20kotlin&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR960IR960&sxsrf=ALeKk02_80H8lSMtHRBiro5oCIHVc5_jcg%3A1629987187353&ei=c6EnYeeQFcSQ_QaSy6GwAQ&oq=return%20multiple%20values%20with%20different%20types%20from%20function%20kotlin&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGABQ9eUlWPXlJWDa5yVoAHACeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwinlqm6787yAhVESN8KHZJlCBYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) and have been heard of `Pair`, `Triple`, `Array<Any>`, `List`, `interface`, `sealed class` or [using the trick of creating data class to return and then destructing](https://medium.com/android-news/this-simple-trick-will-have-you-creating-multiple-returns-in-kotlin-37b9fe2a2f9f), but it seems that most of these are used to return `primitive data types` not `data classes` and since I'm a beginner to Kotlin, I'm a bit confused. Would you please provide me a comprehensive explanation about returning multiple values in Kotlin or introduce me a book/ any other comprehensive text about this issue?

Comment: There's no reason the data class strategy needs to be confined to primitive values. It's the most sensible solution, in my opinion. And you don't necessarily have to use destructuring on the return value. You can assign it to a variable and then inspect each property of the data class.

Comment: You can create a data class inside a function, but then you can't return it because it is private inside the function. Needing to return multiple values from a function is a somewhat rare occurrence, so it shouldn't be a concern to create some classes for the cases where you do. Like in your case, if this function isn't being called from multiple places in your code that need all those intermediate calculations, it probably doesn't need to be broken out into a separate function from where you were calling it from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't support multiple return types. The idiomatic way to do this is to declare a `class` or a `data class` (I'm just making up a name, change to suit):

```
data class CoordinateInverse(
    val horizontalDistance: Double, 
    val heightDifference: Double, 
    val slopePercent: Double, 
    val slopeDistance: Double, 
    val g12DMS: DMSAngle
)
```

And at the end of your function:

```
return CoordinateInverse(
    horizontalDistance,
    heightDifference,
    slopePercent,
    slopeDistance,
    g12DMS
)
```